# how to create xml document on a remote sever using php with utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I have written a php program to create an XML file on the server with UTF-8 encoding. But the resulting XML file always gives question marks (?????) instead of unicode characters. But in the local server, result was proper. What may be the problem?

here is the php code i have used:

```
<?php
$DOMObject = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$list = $DOMObject->createElement("list");
$DOMObject->appendChild($list);
$rec = $DOMObject->createElement("rec");
$list->appendChild($rec);
$id = $DOMObject->createElement("id");
$rec->appendChild($id);
$idText = $DOMObject->createTextNode("mnkarassery");
$id->appendChild($idText);
$name = $DOMObject->createElement("name");
$rec->appendChild($name);
$nameText = $DOMObject->createTextNode("എം.എൻ.കാരശ്ശേരി");
$name->appendChild($nameText);
$DOMObject->save('writers1.xml');
$DOMObject->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: You have to ensure that the php script has UTF-8 encoding too.

Comment: Check if the font exists on the server of execution.

Comment: @Ruben That's completely irrelevant unless you're rendering PDFs or something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the php file is also written in UTF-8.